# what 's the point of adding 'path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))' to the urls.py file of the django project?

Tags: python, django

Folks i've just started learning Django and can't get my head around using `'path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))'` in the urls.py file of the django project.
Here's my root `urls.py` file:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.HomePage.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
    path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('test/',views.TestPage.as_view(),name='test'),
    path('thanks',views.ThanksPage.as_view(),name='thanks'),
    path("posts/", include("posts.urls", namespace="posts")),
    path("groups/",include("groups.urls", namespace="groups")),
    ]
```

and here's my `urls.py` of the accounts app:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), 
    name="login"),
    path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('signup/',views.SignUp.as_view(),name='signup'),
    ]
```

From above, it's obvious that the accounts app is using LoginView and LogoutView for login and logout functionalities. (SignUp view uses UserCreationForm). I also removed `'path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))'` and tried running the server. Apparently, everything seems to work just fine (logging in, logging out and signing up). So what exactly we get by including that in the `urls.py` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well suppose you have lots of apps and each app has some `urls`, if you don't use include you should add all of your urls in one file and this will make your base `urls` file really messy and some of your `urls` may override each other. For example you decide to call an `example 1` view which has similar url path to `example 2` view but the url redirect the request to wrong view, and therefore include can also isolate urls in some ways (such as `namespacing`). Also note that some times you must use include (For example including `router.urls` of DRF). Include also make debugging of urls much faster and easier for you. You can read more about include in Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#include).

Answer (score 0):

Those Django.contrib.auth.urls are urls itself. meaning that when you include them, it automatically includes some built in django urls for example, login, sign up, password reset, password reset confirmation, etc. They are useful if you do not want to do coding on your own, meaning creating your own views.